# Load back original div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm using `.hide()` and `.show()` functions to toggle my page contents, and `.HTML()` to change contents inside a div.

```
$('#wrap').html(' <span id="t-image"> </span> <span id="t-info"> </span>');
```

This will change all contents inside `wrap` div to  `<span id="t-image"> </span> <span id="t-info"> </span>`.

Is there anyway to load back original contents that was inside the the `wrap` div? Or any other way to do this with the capability of loading back contents later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the previous html in, for example, data of that element:

```
var $wrap = $("#wrap");
// Store
$wrap.data("old_html", $wrap.html());
// Update
$wrap.html(' <span id="t-image"> </span> <span id="t-info"> </span>');
// Revert
$wrap.html($wrap.data("old_html"));
```

Comment: but I built a custom code according to your idea!    
var $wrap = $("#wrapper2"); var old_html = $wrap.html(); alert(old_html);

Comment: Yeah, even I didn't notice! Thanks @mishik

Answer (score 1):

You can use append() of jquery

```
 $("#wrap").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
```

This will only add the contents after the existing div contents..:)..

Comment: Appreciated! my propose is to hide original content temporary and show something else, later show em back again!